# DialogFragment show after onPostResume cause IllegalStateException: cannot perform this action

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception, android-support-library

I have an application, that shows different `DialogFragments` in response to different actions(mostly Async ones). I'm using latest revision of Support library(constantly updaring it though SDK Manager)

All the actions throw `Intent` in callback

Intents are processed in the `BroadcastReceiver`, that is registered in `onPostResume` callback(and unregistered in `onPause`).

Dialog is shown immediately after the intent is caught:

```
if(Constants.SHOW_DIALOG_INTENT.equals(intent.getAction()) {
    showDialog();
}
```

Dialogs are shown via [show(FragmentManager, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29) method

So the question is: why am I getting `IllegalStateException` from some users(app is used by 10k+ users, but only 10-15 exceptions are caught so far). I have no idea what can cause this, except for some kind of a race condition(`Activity` is going down between the `showDialog()` and actual `DialogFragment.show()` calls)

What can I do to avoid this(I understand, that 0.1% of errors is acceptable, but I'm just trying to find the problem)?